# Vaadin 8 grid editor doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

Vaadin 8 editor of grid doesn't work correctly when I double click on cell that I can edit.

I use the simple code for create grid and add for one column editor component.

```
VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
content.setMargin(false);
content.setSpacing(false);
content.setSizeFull();
setContent(content);

Grid<OrderModel> grid = new Grid(OrderModel.class);
grid.setItems(generate());
grid.setSizeFull();

grid.getEditor().setEnabled(true);
grid.getColumn("planningStatus").setEditorComponent(getCombobox());
```

Next I run app and start to scroll grid till column "planningStatus".

How it works:
[image]

So. What should I do or how I should fix it for correct open editor in grid?

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: @Alex78191 nope, we choose another approach without inline editor

Comment: componentColumn?

Answer (score 0):

Could your problem be related to issue reported here: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/7746 ?

There exists now also [add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/grideditorcolumnfix-add-on) which fixes couple of known Editor cell sizing issues:

Comment: Yes, It's the same bug but I think maybe someone resolve the bug on Vaadin v8